# Grid Layout with row set to *

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have the layout like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="80" /> <!--Row 1-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!--Row 2-->
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" /> <!--Row 3-->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

*Row 2* must be scalable, so we put its `Height` `*`, we have to.

Question is, we don't want *Row 3* stay at the bottom. In other words, we wish *Row 2* initialized with the needed height.

Currently(*Row 2* has many unsed space at the bottom):

[image]

Wished:

[image]

Is there any simple way to get this?

Comment: So add one more row and leave it blank. As simple as that.

Comment: Have you tried setting Row 2's `Height` to `Auto`? It will still scale

Comment: @Nitesh where put the blank rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the accurate solution myself, but still thanks to @Maverik @Nitesh @Vanlalhriata and so on, you guys helped me a lot.

I wrapper a **Panel** outside the grid, and set its `height` to `Auto`, set `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` too.

Here is my full demo solution, hopes this helps:

```
<!--wrapper a new panel, set its property-->
<Grid Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                    Background="Red"
                    Text="Row 1" />
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                    Background="Navy"
                    Text="Row 3" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This meets all of my requirements, something like Microsoft Word 2013 start page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" /> <!--Row 1-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!--Row 2-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!--Row 3-->            
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

You have to set VerticalAlignment="Top" for the Content of Row 3.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think he wants second row on auto and last should be on * since its the filler.

Comment: I'd prefer not doing this. I'd go with adding a new blank row **if** I had it's height in a percentage as in Row 2 `Height="0.6*"` and blank Row 4 with `Height="0.4*"`. If I had to do what your answer shows, I'd just go with giving a bottom margin of 80 on the `Grid` (`Margin="0 0 0 80"`)

Comment: yes exactly, I taken value 80 from his example to show how it can be done and assume he can do same with static value or percentage as per requirement.

Comment: with that it'll never collapse down even when it should (because row 2 has taken all the available space). He doesn't actually want to keep the space at bottom, just doesn't want the third row to sit at bottom if it isn't needed.

Comment: We want to implement just like **word 2013**. At the start page, _Recent section_ is _Row 2_, _open other projects_ and the above _spliter_ is _Row 3_. If we resize the window height value to lower, the _Row 2_ height changes at the same time, but _Row 3_ is always under _Row 2_, and is visible. Also, no more space under _Row 3_. **In a word, we just the same effect with Word 2013**.

Comment: with that comment from OP, its confirmed that both your height and margin methods are indeed wrong. Its not about what you'd do, its about what OP needs.

Comment: @Nitesh thanks. But Row 4 has the same height with Row 2, means more space under Row 3. It's not correct anyway.

Comment: Ok I guess I know what is the problem here. Stick to your version of it and set VerticalAlignment="Top" for the content of Row3. That should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

You'd want to set a minimum height for your window or a maximum height with scrollviewer for Row 2, otherwise Row 2 can push Row 3 off the view. Here's a sample that shows how this can be played around with:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="480">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Aquamarine">
            <TextBlock>Page Header Stuff</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkKhaki">
            <TextBlock TextTrimming="None" TextWrapping="Wrap">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="DarkCyan">
            <TextBlock>Row 3</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Background="DarkGray"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: If this is the OP's desired behavior, why even opt for a Grid in the first place and not just go with a `StackPanel`? Row 1's `Border` can set it's Height as 80, and we can get rid of the Border number 4.

Comment: I had suggested Dockpanel + StackPanel combo in chat but I didn't get a response so I just posted grid solution. OP actually solved the problem by switching Row 3 to 80 height and Row 2 to auto as per my last chat with him in wpf room.